# How to prevent marker from repeating in clustermanager?

Tags: android, arrays, list, arraylist, collections

I'm using geofire library to load data from firebase 3 in a specifique region, but when i add new marker to database and i check my map i found out that multiple marker has been added in the same latlng coordinates, my question is how to prevent marker from been repeating in the same coordinates. Here is the Geofire methode :

```
             geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                    try{
                        MyItem myItem = new MyItem(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                        if (!items.contains(myItem)) {
                            items.add(myItem);
                        }
                        Log.d("onKey","called");
                    }catch (ClassCastException e){
                        Log.d("classCastException","");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                   // countingMarkers = 0;
                    parseJsonToList();
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

ParseJsonToList methode :

```
private void parseJsonToList() {


        itemss = clusterManagerAlgorithm.getItems();
        try {


            items.removeAll(itemss);
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            Log.d("itemsDoesn't exist"," : ");
        }


        mClusterManager.clearItems();
        mClusterManager.cluster();
        mClusterManager.addItems(items);
        Log.d("items"," : " + items);


    }
```